# Stop click event for a control when it associated label(HtmlFor) is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am using ExtJS 5. I am using the textfield(Ext.form.field.Text) and set it's fieldLabel config. Now in the actual html labels that are generated and they have their HtmlFor property set to that textfield.

I am handling click event on the DOM element. Since "HtmlFor" is set, click on the label, fires click for textfield as well.

I am handling click at label level and I don't want it to propogate to textfield. Is there a way I can stop it? Event.stopPropogation does not work.

Or if it propogates to textfield, I want to know that it was fired because initially label was clicked. Currently I am doing this by setting a global variable and noting label click there and then checking on textfield click, if label was clicked previously. Is there a better or standard way in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think  you can use `xtype:label` and then use

```
`labelCmp.on("click", this.callyourmethod, this)`
```

to handle click event .Here  you are making them independent of each other.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But they are already independent. I want to either stop the click event from occuring on input once it has occured on label. Or atleast have some information that it's associated label was previously clicked.